# Efficiently removing empty spaces within set of numbers

Tags: algorithm, packing

I'll use Python syntax and objects to represent the problem, but in reality it's meant for a model in SQL databases, with a Python API and ORM.

I have a list of numbers like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

From time to time, some numbers get removed and null spaces remain:

```
[0, 1, 2, None, None, 5, 6, None, None, None, 10]
```

What I need to do is to efficiently pack this set of numbers on a maintenance step done periodically, both in ordered and unordered fashion, such that no null spaces remain between numbers:

So, in ordered fashion I need that list to become:

```
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 10, None, None, None, None, None]
```

And when unordered it doesn't really matter where each number goes, as long as there are no null spaces between them.

Numbers can be moved in contiguous blocks, and moving them any number of places to left or right costs the same, but there's a setup and teardown cost which makes it a lot more efficient to move larger blocks and achieve it in as few updates as possible.

Right now I'm using the most simple solution, finding blocks of contiguous numbers and moving them to the nearest left one block at a time until it's packed. So, in the example, 5, 6 is moved 2 blocks left in a single update, and then 10 is moved 5 blocks to left in another update.

```
[0, 1, 2, None, None, 5, 6, None, None, None, 10]

[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, None, None, None, None, None, 10]

[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 10, None, None, None, None, None]
```

This trivial approach seems to be the most efficient when order matters, but in reality most of my operations will be unordered and I think there should be a better approach. For instance, in this case, the list can be packed in a single update by moving the 0, 1, 2 block between 6 and 10:

```
[None, None, None, None, None, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 10]
```

In reality there will be thousands of blocks, but I know beforehand the size of each block and each gap. Moving blocks is also very expensive compared to the computation needed for combinatorics between their size and the gaps, so finding the optimal solution is the ideal.

This seems a kind of bin packing problem, but I really don't know how to approach it to find the best solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I started writing out an answer of framing this as simple A* search, but the heuristic that I thought of isn't actually admissible... Anyway, that might be a reasonable approach, though I bet if you have thousands of blocks (meaning lots of possible moves) there are probably much more efficient approaches.

Comment: What is the range of numbers? Is that [0...10] or any integer?

Comment: Any integer in 64 bits range.

Comment: 1) must the original 'None' entries be kept intact (not overwritten but moved) 1a) If so: is their relative order important?  2) Can you afford an auxilliary array of N ints?

Comment: @wildplasser 1) the None entries don't even exist in the database. I show them here for clarification only. 2) I can afford anything for the solution, since the whole moving operation is likely to take hours to complete.

Comment: I did not mean databases, but respecting the None-entries (by not overwriting them). Still not clear what your intentions are.  I'll add my contribution, and see what happens. (in pseudo-pseudo code ;)

Comment: BTW, what is your exact cost measure? eg your proposed swap into `[None, None, None, None, None, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 10]` will cost one swap for three items, but -> `[0, 1, 2, 10, None, 5, 6, None, None, None, None]` -> `[0, 1, 2, 10, 6, 5, None, None, None, None, None]` will cost two swaps for only two items.

Comment: Swaps cost the same, no matter the distance, and for practical purposes, no matter how many items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the unordered case, suppose that somebody tells you what spaces the final contiguous block should fill. Then one heuristic is to suppose that if you move in the largest blocks outside this region into it first, then everything will fit and you don't have to break any blocks up. As suggested in the comment, you could run A* (or branch and bound) with this. Then your first decision is where the final contiguous block should be, but this is just another level of A*/branch and bound - in fact under this heuristic, the most promising final contiguous region will be the one currently holding the largest number of filled in sub-regions, because you are assuming that you only have to move in sub-regions outside this.

If you do find this is too expensive, one way to speed up branch and bound, at the cost of getting poorer answers, is to discard possible answers that could improve the best answer found so far by only X%, for some X.

Actually I think you can get a slightly better lower bound than this - max(number of separate contiguous gaps in the target area, number of separate contiguous areas to be moved in from source area) should be slightly better as one move can at best move in a single contiguous area of numbers and fill a single gap in the target area.

One easy way to get a lower bound is to ignore enough constraints on the problem to make it easy. Assuming that the unknown correct answer is still a feasible solution this must give you a lower bound, because a best solution on the weakened problem must be at least as good as the unknown correct answer. You can apply this to your problem with gappy updates by pretending that two updates will never collide with each other. Given a specified target area, computing this heuristic amounts to finding a best way to cut up the source area into chunks, each of which fit into the target area. You could solve this with a dynamic program: you work out best answer for the first n+1 cells of the source area by considering all possible ways of copying in the last k cells of the source area, and then adding on the cost of copying in the first n+1-k cells of the source area, which you will have already worked out. Unfortunately, I have no idea of whether this heuristic is strong enough to be useful.

Comment: I'm trying the branch and bound approach, but actually an update can move any contiguous block, including the gaps in it. So, for instance, [0, 1, -, -, -, 5, 6, -, 8, -, 10] can be done as [0, 1, 5, 6, -, 8, -, -, -, -, 10] then [0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 8, -, -, -, -, -]. I've not considered it so far because it seemed to complicate things a little more, but it would be a little better than building the large [5, 6, 10, 8] block first and moving it.

Comment: I actually implemented the solution using your first suggestion, to assume that moving the largest blocks into the packing region first they will fit and breaking them as needed. I'm now adding pre and post optimizations to that operation, both attempting to build bigger blocks that will fit by doing what I mentioned on my previous comment, but also breaking blocks in a way that the remaining 1 or 2 pieces will fit the gaps for the next cycles. Choosing the cheapest one among the most promising gives me good enough results so far.

Comment: One idea I have not implemented is to find the most promising final region first, because I found some issues in my application with leaving empty spaces on the left after the packing operation, but I'm considering implementing it and checking if it's worth doing it and making one final pack with the whole block a few steps left.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you describe is called the [compaction problem](http://dx.doi.org.mutex.gmu.edu/10.1006/jagm.1993.1019). In the classical compaction problem (both order and unordered variants), the cost of data movement is not seen as so prohibitive. So, it can be trivially solved by using an auxiliary storage and copying non-empty entries into the auxiliary storage in a single linear scan. The new compacted storage can simply replace the original or copied over to the original, depending on the context. Now, all of this can be done in linear time, and using only linear additional storage. So, it is not considered a hard problem in the sense that bin-packing is. For bean packing, there is absolutely no easy solution whether or not you allow a linear amount of extra storage. So, clearly what we're dealing with here is not bin-packing.

When data movement is costly, there is now the additional constraint of minimizing the number of movements of non-contiguous data blocks. One can look at this problem as an instance of either of the two problems:

1. **In-place sorting of a binary array**. Here, you model your array as containing only two kinds of data -- 0s and 1s. This can easily be achieved in your case using a predicate isNull(a) that returns 1 for an empty data entry and 0 for a non-empty one. The simplest solution I can think of here is to use [Selection Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)  for sorting the binary array.  It never does more than *O(n)* data movements in the worst-case, even though it can make *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* number of comparisons, but you don't mind that, since you only want to minimize the number of data movements. If there's no data to move, it doesn't do any!  Some improvements that complicate things a bit could be:

   - To swap blocks rather than individual entries. By this I mean, two blocks (one of zeros and the other of ones) can be swapped only if the zero block is bigger. You could also use the greedy heuristic that the next swap is always the one that minimizes the absolute difference of these two i.e. abs(len(zeroBlock) - len(oneBlock)). This would only work for the unordered instance of your problem.
   - Two other optimizations would be to do a preprocessing to decide weather to sort ascending or descending.
   - Also, you might want to exclude contiguous ends of the list.
2. **[Garbage Compaction](http://benediktmeurer.de/files/fast-garbage-compaction-with-interior-pointers.pdf)**. Essentially, the idea is to consider the free spaces as deallocated space in memory that need to be garbage collected. For this let me refer you to this interesting [SO discussion thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130227/what-is-a-good-algorithm-for-compacting-records-in-a-blocked-file) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663292/how-does-heap-compaction-work-quickly). You might also find this [research paper](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/hosking/690M/p532-cohen.pdf) or [this one](http://benediktmeurer.de/files/fast-garbage-compaction-with-interior-pointers.pdf) useful.

Good luck!

Comment: The compaction problem was my initial approach to it, but actually couldn't find any docs about it, all leading to data compaction algorithms. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define IS_EMPTY(c) ((c) <= '@')

unsigned moverup(char buff[], unsigned size)
{
unsigned src,dst,cnt;

for (src=dst=cnt=0; src < size; src++ ) {
        if (!IS_EMPTY(buff[src])) { cnt++; continue; }
        if (!cnt) continue;
ugly:
        memmove(buff+dst, buff+src-cnt, cnt );
        dst += cnt;
        cnt = 0;
        }
if (cnt) goto ugly;
return dst;
}

int main(void)
{
unsigned result;
char array[] = "qwe@rty@ui#op";

printf("Before:%s\n", array );

result = moverup (array, strlen (array) );

printf("result:%u\n", result );
// entries beyond result will contain garbage now.
// array[result] = 0;
printf("After:%s\n", array );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you're willing to help, but this has nothing to do with the problem at hand. At most it does what I said I'm already doing for the ordered sets.

Comment: Well, then rephrase your question. What is it that you want to avoid? Moving the same item multiple times? Overwriting/clobbering the empty slots? Maybe I could answer your question if you would formulate it better. Maybe you want the perfect shuffle? Do the elements have the same size?

Comment: There's certainly no formulation problem, since the other users who answered it understood it perfectly. What I want is to eliminate the empty gaps in the set by swapping them with the numbers in as few moving operations as possible.

Comment: That's what I did. I just used the <= '@' pseudocode to mark the vacant elements and to illustrate the shift down operation. But: so you *do* want the minimal number of swaps, and you dont want to disturb the empty cells. Why didn't you say so ?

Comment: That's what you did for the ordered packing. As I said on the question, this is solved by a trivial solution, and it's not the real problem. Finding the minimal number of operations for the **unordered** packing is the real problem, and it's not a trivial one. What happens to the empty cells don't matter, as long as they are all in a single contiguous block.

Comment: If they are equal-sized, and order is not important in the result (except that the empty cells should be moved to the right) there is a trivial solution which needs fewer swaps than my snippet.